# How to use a regex to organize song lists, changing their order from "Song - Artist" to "Artist - Song"?

Tags: notepad++, regex, playlists

I have a long list of songs in the format "Artist - Song", but I want them to be listed as "Artist - Song". How to change all items automatically with a regular expression, preferably on Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Notepad++**:

1. Click before the first letter in your file for the search to run throughout the complete list
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the text editor `Replace` dialog
3. Check the `Regular expression` search mode
4. Type `(.*?)\s-\s(.*)` in the "Find what" field. It means "select and save everything until a hyphen preceded by a space" and then "everything after the hyphen followed by a space"
5. Type `\2 - \1` in the `Replace with` field to insert the two sets reversed
6. Click on `Replace all`

Note: if it doesn't work, make sure that the list uses the same hyphen character as the one you typed into the `Find what` field.

[image: Screenshot of the Notepad++ "Replace" dialog]